# Why isn't sed greedy in this simple case?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

```
$echo "foo 65 bar" | sed -n -e 's/.*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
5
```

Why is the output not `65`?  Shouldn't sed greedily match the `[0-9]\+` part?  How do I tell sed to match all of `65`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.*` is greedy first -- it's matching `foo 6`. The only reason it stops there is because matching any further would stop the whole pattern from matching, so it leaves the `5` for the `([0-9]+)`. If you made it `([0-9]*)` instead the `.*` would match the whole line and you'd get nothing in your group. One way around it is to tell the first part not to match numbers:

```
$ echo "foo 65 bar" | sed -n -e 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
65
```